# Can you do a repeat in an if else statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement, applescript

I have a script:

```
property firstRow : 2090
property lastRow : 5584

set r to firstRow

-- highly recommended
-- close all of Safari's windows before...
tell application "Safari"
close windows
end tell


-- loop through the given row numbers
repeat until r is (lastRow + 1)

-- get the search value for Safari auto completion (column J)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        tell active sheet
            set searchTerm to string value of range ("J" & r) of active sheet
            set searchTerm1 to string value of range ("J" & r-1) of active sheet
            if searchTerm1=searchTerm then 
            set r to r + 1
            end tell
            end tell 
            end repeat
            else
            set searchTerm to searchTerm1
            end if
        end tell
    end tell

-- open Safari and make a new window
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:""}
    delay 0.5
    set pageLoaded to false
end tell

-- type the search value into the address field and hit return (aka select and open the first proposal)
tell application "System Events"
    -- here with Safari 6.1 text field 1 of group 2 of tool bar 1 of window 1 points to the URL field
    set focused of text field 1 of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of process "Safari" to true
    delay 0.5
    keystroke searchTerm
    delay 1.5
    keystroke return
end tell

-- let open Safari the suggested web page and read out the finally used URL
tell application "Safari"
    repeat while not pageLoaded -- keep doing this loop until loading complete
        delay 5
        if (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is "complete" then
            set pageLoaded to true
        else
            -- not sure if this second else is needed, why not just wait until the first access has finished...

            -- close document 1
            -- make new document with properties {URL:""}
            -- tell application "System Events"
            --  delay 1.5
            --  set focused of text field 1 of group 2 of tool bar 1 of window 1 of process "Safari" to true
            --  delay 1.5
            --  keystroke searchTerm
            --  delay 1.5
            --  keystroke return
            -- end tell
        end if
        set thisULR to "NO SITE"
    end repeat
    try
        set thisURL to URL of document 1
    on error
        set thisURL to "NO SITE"
    end try
    close document 1
end tell

-- write the result into the cell next to the key word (column K)
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        if thisURL then
        tell active sheet
            make new hyperlink of cell ("K" & r) with properties {address:thisURL, name:thisURL}
        end tell
    else
        tell active sheet
            make new cell ("K" & r) with properties {name:"NO SITE"}
        end tell
    end if

end tell

set r to r + 1
end repeat
```

It basically works except for the first if then else statement. I hope what i am trying to do here is clear. I am pretty new to applescript and would really appreciate your help. I'm trying to do if this happens then restart the script with the next r value, but if it doesn't then continue the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the "end tell" of a tell block inside an if clause that follows it. You can't do:

```
tell app "Microsoft Excel"
    If a = 1
    set a to 2
end tell
else if...
```

You have to make your script look more like:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        set searchTerm to string value of range ("J" & r) of active sheet
        set searchTerm1 to string value of range ("J" & r - 1) of active sheet
    end tell
end tell

if searchTerm1 = searchTerm then
    set r to r + 1
    exit repeat
else
    set searchTerm to searchTerm1
end if
```

Another problem is you're wanting to exit a repeat conditionally, I think. If so, you use "Exit repeat" in one part of a conditional within a repeat block to exit the repeat. So, try and rewrite with those two things in mind.

Comment: Thank you. But if I write exit repeat then won't it not repeat with the higher r value? I want it to repeat with the new r value and not continue with the rest of the script with the old r value.